# Is there a way to access a file inside a .zip in a Linux environment

Tags: zip

I want to find a specific line of text inside of a file and print it on my screen using Linux commands. I know I could do:

```
find -name '[filename]' | xargs grep -i ‘[text I'm looking for inside file]'
```

However, my file is inside a .zip file. I know unzip -l [.zip file name] will list of all files inside of .zip file, but it won't let me access in order to "grep" the information I need.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Do you only want bash or shell solutions? Depending on the context, I'd probably be inclined to use [python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html). You can update your question and/or tags to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_zip tool from the open-source [Zip-Ada](http://unzip-ada.sf.net/) project.

1. get / download the sources
2. build with the command `gnatmake -P zipada` (you get GNAT through apt or yum)
3. you have now a binary find_zip.

`Usage: find_zip archive[.zip] ["]text["]`